# AngularJS: UI-Router when switching tabs the first one is always selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-router

I have the following html markup:

```html
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 panel-container">
  <tabset vertical="true" type="pills">
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabsViews" select="selectView(tab.index)" class=" {{tabsViews[tab.index-1]['invalid'] ? 'invalid-tab': 'valid-tab' }}">
      <tab-heading>{{tab.title}}</tab-heading>
    </tab>
  </tabset>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 panel-container">
  <div data-ui-view data-autoscroll="false"></div>
</div>
```

and in the controller I defined my tabs this way:

```js
$scope.tabsViews = [{
  index: 1,
  name: 'accountUDFs',
  invalid: false,
  title: resourceFactory.getResource('Labels', 'xUDFs').format(resourceFactory.getResource('Labels', 'account'))
}, {
  index: 2,
  name: 'invoiceUDFs',
  invalid: false,
  title: resourceFactory.getResource('Labels',
    'xUDFs').format(resourceFactory.getResource('Labels', 'invoice'))
}, {
  index: 3,
  name: 'confirmationText',
  invalid: false,
  title: resourceFactory.getResource('Labels', 'confirmationText')
}];
```

and I defined the following states:

```js
app.config(['$stateProvider',
  function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
      url: '/',
      controller: 'prefsAcsController',
      template: ''
    }).state('edit', {
      url: '/edit',
      controller: 'prefsAcsCrudController',
      templateUrl: '/customerAccounts/PrefsAcs'
    }).state('accountUDFs', {
      url: '/AccountUDFs',
      templateUrl: '/customerAccounts/PrefsAcs/AccountsUDFs'
    }).state('invoiceUDFs', {
      url: '/InvoiceUDFs',
      templateUrl: '/customerAccounts/PrefsAcs/InvoiceUDFs'
    }).state('confirmationText', {
      url: '/ConfirmationText',
      templateUrl: '/customerAccounts/PrefsAcs/ConfirmationText'
    });
  }
]);
```

So, when I just go to the Preferences page from the menu, the first tab is selected and all is good.

However, I also added a link to the second tab in another page

```html
<a href='/CustomerAccounts/PrefsAcs#/InvoiceUDFs'>
```

now, when I click on this link, I still see a message in Console that the first tab is about to be activated and that tab is highlighted. But I see the content of the second tab which is what I want in this case.

Do you know what makes the first tab automatically selected?

Do you know what should I do to skip that selectView code when I come with that full URL and to have the correct tab highlighted ?

Comment: Try to create the HTML link to the other tab by using [ui-sref](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref).

Comment: I am afraid this would not work as that state is defined in a different controller. In other words, from the main menu I call Customer/Invoices/InvoicesUserDefined and I need to switch to Customer/Preferences. Each menu item has its own controller with states defined at the top. Unless I define that state in the Accounts controller (called from the first menu) as well. I'm going to try that idea